# Inventário com Android

Tags: java, android, radiobutton

Estou tentando criar um app para controle de produto tipo um inventário, no caso o usuário seleciona no `RadioButton` o produto e depois com scanner vai ler o serial do equipamento.

O scanner está funcionando, mas as opções de `RadioButton` e da lista de inventário não. Eu me basei no código do Renato Mattos e vou salvar as informações no BD. Segue o código.

```
package com.blogspot.wellingtonmiyake.radiobutton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText txtNome, txtIdade;
    TextView txtResultado, contextTxt;
    RadioGroup radioGroupInf;
    Button btnok, btnCapture;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        txtIdade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCode);
        contextTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_content);

        txtResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);
        radioGroupInf = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupInf);

        btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        final Activity activity = this;
        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                //integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);

                integrator.setPrompt("CAMERA SCAN");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

        btnok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnok);
        btnok.setOnClickListener(this);

        String nome = txtNome.getText().toString();
        String idade = txtIdade.getText().toString();
       // String scan = contextTxt.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() != null ){
                //String resultContents = result.getContents();
                contextTxt.setText("scan"+result);
                alert (result.getContents());
            }else{
                //alert ("Scan Cancelado");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

        } else {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    private  void alert(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    String imprimir = "Teste de botão radio" ;




        if(radioGroupInf.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1){
           RadioButton  selecao = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioGroupInf.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            imprimir += "" +selecao.getText().toString();

        }

        txtResultado.setText(imprimir +txtNome.getText()+txtIdade.getText()+contextTxt.getText());
    }

   }
```

Comment: Qual é a sua pergunta?

Comment: A pergunta é que no meu codigo quando chamo a btnCapture apresenta mais informação que deveria.